# Change page color and image with JS

Tags: javascript, html, events

```js
const element = document.querySelector("body")
element.addEventListener('click', changeBackground)

function changeBackground (){
    element.classList.toggle('active')
}

const newImg = document.getElementById("newImage")
newImg.addEventListener('click', changeImage)

function changeImage(){
   newImg.setAttribute('src', './public/SwitcherLight.svg')
}
```

When I click on the image it changes the image and the background color of the page, but when I click back, only the background color goes back to how it was before, I want the same to happen with the image but I can't

Comment: So set the class of the body.....

Comment: this is not the problem, I need that when I click on the image it changes, and when I click again it goes back to how it was before, and this is not happening, with the page color I was able to do it

Comment: Well I answered our original question. Your edit changed it to a different question so of course that is no longer the problem. You would need to set a new image source.

Comment: yes i just saw that i asked wrong later. sorry

Answer (score -2):

```js
image = document.querySelector("#image");
changed_img=false

image.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.body.classList.toggle('blue');      
  if (changed_img) {
    image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png";
    changed_img=false
  } else {
  image.src="https://i.insider.com/602ee9ced3ad27001837f2ac?width=700"
    changed_img=true
  }
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body class="red">
  <img height="200" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/640px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" id="image">
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helped.